# Change in the response format of solrj

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene, solrj

Previously I was using the solrj 4.9.1 for connecting with solrserver 4.9.1.
Now I have upgraded it to solrj 5.4.1 to connect with solrserver 5.4.1. But the problem is that previously the code,

```
QueryResponse res = null;
try {
    res=solrServer.query(query);
} catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

used to work properly. But now in solrj 5.4.1 it is throwing an IO Exception for processing the same data. When I have changed the code as,

```
QueryResponse res = null;
    try {
        solrServer.query(query);
    } catch (SolrServerException | IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

it is passing through. Although I am not getting any result set. But there is no error during the query. So what I think is that there is some problem or change in the QueryResponse constructor. But I have not found any change in the solrj documentation.
Both in 5.4.1 as well as in 4.9.1
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_4_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/QueryResponse.html

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/QueryResponse.html
 only that SolrServer is changed to SolrClient. Is there really any change? or I am doing it wrongly?

Comment: Are those code samples right? In the upper you do an assignment of the result `res=solrServer.query(query);`. In the lower that assignment is missing `solrServer.query(query);`. There you lack the `res=`.

Comment: @cheffe Actually what I was trying to find out that weather the query line was actually executing or there was an error while mapping the result to the response.

Comment: What I have recently found is that I was adding some sorting criteria to the query as `sort=RECEIVEDATE_dt+asc` . So that part is creating the issue. If I omit that part then the output is working fine. Actually from solr 5.0.0 I have found that some element of the data in xml format is indexed as array while there were indexed as String previously. I guess that is causing the issue while sorting.